# How can I create a custom navigation drawer in react-native using react-navigation v5?

Tags: react-native, frontend, navigation-drawer, react-navigation-drawer

I am looking to create a custom drawer navigator with a few expandable list views with a few hidden routes.

E.g.

Home

Main1

Hidden 1

hid a

hid b

Hidden 2

hid a

hid b

Where hid a and hid b would be hidden behind hidden 1 or hidden 2. When hidden 1 or hidden 2 is clicked or touched the hid a/hid b would be displayed.

This is what I have so far --

Main.js:

```
export default function MainScreen({ navigation }){
  
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName='Home' drawerContent={props => <Menu {... props} />}>
        <Drawer.Screen name=".." options={{drawerIcon: config => <Icon name=".." size={22} color="#000"></Icon>}} component={HomeScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Ex1" component={Ex1} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Ex2" component={Ex2} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Ex3" component={Ex3} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Ex4" component={Ex4} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Ex5" component={Ex5} options={{
            title:"..",
            drawerIcon: config => <Icon
                size={22}
                name='..'></Icon>
        }} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

Menu.js:

```
const Menu = (props) => {

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
      <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
        <DrawerItemList {...props} />
        
      </DrawerContentScrollView>

    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

And I'm looking to split out DrawerItemList so I can display a few of my routes within a dropdown.

Much of the code in the samples above has been sanitised because a lot of it is commercially sensitive but I can assure you my component names etc are much better in the actual code.

Any suggestions or comments would be much appreciated.

I have just started working with react-native so bare with me.

If you need any more info, please don't hesitate to comment and ask.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to use @eliav2/react-native-collapsible-view for the collapsible view with DrawerItems inside.